# How to change value of outer variable using a inner function?

Tags: javascript

In following code, the outer variables playerScore and computerScore are not updated when I use the function calcScore? How do I update it, using a function? From what I understand, it is possible to change the value of the outer variable from an inner scope, but why does it not work here?

```
    <script>
        function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
            playerSelection = playerSelection.toLowerCase();
            computerSelection = computerSelection.toLowerCase();
            if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
                return "draw";
            }
            else if (playerSelection === "rock"){
                if (computerSelection === "scissors") return "win";
                else if (computerSelection === "paper") return "lose";
            }
            else if (playerSelection === "paper"){
                if (computerSelection === "scissors") return "lose";
                else if (computerSelection === "rock") return "win";
            }
            else if (playerSelection === "scissors"){
                if (computerSelection === "rock") return "lose";
                else if (computerSelection === "paper") return "win";
            }
        }
        
        function computerSelection() {
            let selection = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
            return selection[Math.floor(Math.random() * selection.length)];
        }
        function calcScore(result, playerScore, computerScore) {
            if (result === "win") {
                playerScore += 1;
                console.log("win");
            }
            else if (result === "lose") {
                computerScore += 1;
                console.log("lose");
            }
            else if (result === "draw") {
                playerScore += 1;
                computerScore += 1;
            }
        }
        function game() {
            let playerScore = 0;
            let computerScore = 0;
            for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                let result = playRound(prompt("Select rock, paper, or scissors!"), computerSelection());
                calcScore(result, playerScore, computerScore);
                console.log(`You have ${playerScore} points! Computer has ${computerScore} points!`);
            }
            playerScore, computerScore = 0, 0;
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript doesn't pass variables by reference - so any modifications you do to `playerScore` and `computerScore` within `calcScore()` are only local to that function.

What you can do is make `playerScore` and `computerScore` global variables. That way any modifications will be in the global scope. Alternatively, you could have `calcScore()` return the modified values.

Using the global method:

```
    <script>
        let playerScore = 0;
        let computerScore = 0;

        function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
            playerSelection = playerSelection.toLowerCase();
            computerSelection = computerSelection.toLowerCase();
            if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
                return "draw";
            }
            else if (playerSelection === "rock"){
                if (computerSelection === "scissors") return "win";
                else if (computerSelection === "paper") return "lose";
            }
            else if (playerSelection === "paper"){
                if (computerSelection === "scissors") return "lose";
                else if (computerSelection === "rock") return "win";
            }
            else if (playerSelection === "scissors"){
                if (computerSelection === "rock") return "lose";
                else if (computerSelection === "paper") return "win";
            }
        }
        
        function computerSelection() {
            let selection = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
            return selection[Math.floor(Math.random() * selection.length)];
        }
        function calcScore(result) {
            if (result === "win") {
                playerScore += 1;
                console.log("win");
            }
            else if (result === "lose") {
                computerScore += 1;
                console.log("lose");
            }
            else if (result === "draw") {
                playerScore += 1;
                computerScore += 1;
            }
        }
        function game() {

            for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                let result = playRound(prompt("Select rock, paper, or scissors!"), computerSelection());
                calcScore(result);
                console.log(`You have ${playerScore} points! Computer has ${computerScore} points!`);
            }
            playerScore, computerScore = 0, 0;
        }
    </script>
```

Alternative method:

```
    <script>
        function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
            playerSelection = playerSelection.toLowerCase();
            computerSelection = computerSelection.toLowerCase();
            if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
                return "draw";
            }
            else if (playerSelection === "rock"){
                if (computerSelection === "scissors") return "win";
                else if (computerSelection === "paper") return "lose";
            }
            else if (playerSelection === "paper"){
                if (computerSelection === "scissors") return "lose";
                else if (computerSelection === "rock") return "win";
            }
            else if (playerSelection === "scissors"){
                if (computerSelection === "rock") return "lose";
                else if (computerSelection === "paper") return "win";
            }
        }
        
        function computerSelection() {
            let selection = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
            return selection[Math.floor(Math.random() * selection.length)];
        }
        function calcScore(result, playerScore, computerScore) {
            if (result === "win") {
                playerScore += 1;
                console.log("win");
            }
            else if (result === "lose") {
                computerScore += 1;
                console.log("lose");
            }
            else if (result === "draw") {
                playerScore += 1;
                computerScore += 1;
            }

            return [playerScore, computerScore];
        }
        function game() {
            let playerScore = 0;
            let computerScore = 0;
            for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                let result = playRound(prompt("Select rock, paper, or scissors!"), computerSelection());
                let scores = calcScore(result, playerScore, computerScore);
                playerScore += scores[0];
                computerScore += scores[1]; 
                console.log(`You have ${playerScore} points! Computer has ${computerScore} points!`);
            }
            playerScore, computerScore = 0, 0;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: can you give an example of the alternative method?

Answer (score 0):

your defining both of those variables twice so now im confused. do you want to be abled to reuse those variables in the game function without re defining them? because if thats the case then they should be global variables instead of function parameters(you wont be able to use those defined in the function parameter outside of that function).

Comment: oh I wanted to reset the points whenever a round of 5 is completed

Comment: oh that makes sense sorry.